# Aspects of probability space and random variable

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to make sense of various aspects of a probability space and a random variable and how they relate, and would like some help to tie it all together/ verify my understanding this far:

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F,P})$, that models a random experiment, for example: flipping a fair coin twice.

A sample space $\Omega$ contains objects (could be "non-mathematical" objects), also referred to as outcomes of the random experiment, for example: $\Omega = \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$

A sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ (of our choice) contains subsets of $\Omega$ called events i.e. subsets of "non-mathematical" objects, for example: $\mathcal{F}=\{\varnothing,\{TT\},\{HT,TH,HH\},\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}\}$, or, another example: $\mathcal{F}=\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ (i.e. the power set of $\Omega$).

A probability measure $\mathcal{P}$ (of our choice) assigns probabilities to the events i.e. assignes probabilities to the subsets of "non-mathematical" objects in $\mathcal{F}$, 
for example: $\mathcal{P}$ could be defined as: $P(\{\varnothing\})=0$, $P(\{TT\})=0.25$, $P(\{HT,TH,HH\})=0.75$, $P(\{HH,HT,TH,TT\})=1$. 
(In the case of a fair coin).

A random variable $X$ (of our choice) maps some or all of the events in $\mathcal{F}$ to values (in a measurable space $(E,\mathcal{E})$), for example: a random variable $X$ has the following mappings: $\{TT\}$ is mapped to 1, $\{HT,TH,HH\}$ is mapped to 2, $\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$ is mapped to 3.

And, the probabilities given to the events in $\mathcal{F}$ by $\mathcal{P}$ are "transfered"/ "pushed forward" to the values of $X$ in $(E, \mathcal{E})$, for example: $P({TT})=0.25 = f(x=1)$, where $f(x)$ is the pmf of $X$.

**Clarification 1**: Given any combination of mutually exclusive events in $\mathcal{F}$ there should exist an associated probability distribution, which should be the "same" as the probability distribution of a random variable that assigns values to that specific combination of mutually exclusive events, right?

**Clarification 2**: And as such the probability measure $\mathcal{P}$ in regard to a combination of mutually exclusive events in $\mathcal{F}$ should be the "same" as the pmf/pdf of a random variable that maps those events to values, only the inputs to $\mathcal{P}$ are events instead of values (like with the pmf/pdf). Correct?

Comment: I followed everything you wrote, then, I could not make heads or tails of your Clarifications 1 and 2 (pun intended). =)  Can you give an example of what you mean? Say for this example related to "Clarification 1":  $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$; $\mathcal{F}$ the set of all subsets of $\Omega$; the "combination of mutually exclusive events in $\mathcal{F}$" being $\{1,2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}$.

Comment: @Michael Given your example where the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ is the power set of $\Omega$. Let's say I pick a combination of mutually exclusive events in $\mathcal{F}$ say the events {1,2}, {3}, {4}, {5,6} then my probability measure $\mathcal{P}$ tells me the probability for each of those events (right?) and I could perceive of a probability distribution. Furthermore, if I define a random variable that maps each of those events to values then I could also think of a probability distribution for those values, and these two probability distributions are the "same", that's my question :)

Comment: It feels intuitive to me, but I feel I might miss-understand something because I have never read it presented like this.

Comment: You seem to have added $\{5,6\}$ to ensure your "combination of mutually exclusive events" has a union of the whole space $\Omega$.  This is called a **partition of $\Omega$**.  My answer below anticipated this was your intended meaning, I think it may answer your question. Note that it likely is not helpful to give imprecise claims of two distributions as "same" as it would depend on what specifically you are intending.  [Is an apple the "same" as an orange as long as we add quotes?] You can define a new sample space if you want (you can do anything you want); that is part of my answer below.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I was talking about a partition, but I suppose one could talk of a "non-partition" of events and the probability distribution being only those events (the sum of all probabilities in the probability distribution having a sum of less than 1).

Comment: Well, that was my original example, but you changed it.  I had $\{1,2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}$.  You  added $\{5,6\}$.  If we remove $\{5,6\}$, it sounds like you are talking about conditional probability?

Comment: @Michael I hadn't thought about it like a conditional probability distribution but I guess that's what it is if one talks about a non-partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the same event in multiple ways. For example suppose the sample space is the set of outcomes of two flips of a coin: 
$$ \Omega = \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$$
The sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all subsets of $\Omega$. 
Now define a random variable $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as the number of heads:
$$ Y(HH) = 2 , Y(HT) = 1, Y(TH)=1, Y(TT)=0$$
The following are different ways of specifying the **same event**: 
$$\{\mbox{there are 2 heads}\} =  \{HH\} = \{\omega \in \Omega : Y(\omega)=2\} = \{Y=2\} $$
All of these are the **same event** and so of course:
$$P[\mbox{there are 2 heads}]= P[\{HH\}] = P[\{\omega \in \Omega : Y(\omega)=2\}] =  P[Y=2]$$
Because these are all the same event, there is no need to “redefine” or “push-forward” anything.

---

If you want to define a function $f:\{0, 1,2\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(y) = P[Y=y]$, then nobody will stop you.  Since the events $\{Y=0\}$, $\{Y=1\}$, $\{Y=2\}$ partition the sample space (they are disjoint events and their union is the whole sample space), the third axiom of probability ensures 
$$P[Y=0]+P[Y=1]+P[Y=2]=P[\Omega]$$
and we also know $P[\Omega]=1$. 
If you want to write the above equation using your function $f$, then indeed $f(0)+f(1)+f(2)=1$.

---

If for some reason you want to define a new sample space $\mathcal{Y} = \{0,1,2\}$, sigma algebra $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ being the set of all subsets of $\mathcal{Y}$, and probability measure $\tilde{P}[A]$ defined for all $A \subseteq \mathcal{Y}$ by 
$$\tilde{P}[A] = \sum_{y \in A} f(y)$$ 
then nobody will stop you (and you can verify this satisfies the three axioms of probability).

More generally, if $\mathcal{Z}$ is any finite or countably infinite set and if $g:\mathcal{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function that satisfies $g(z)\geq 0$ for all $z \in \mathcal{Z}$ and
$\sum_{z \in \mathcal{Z}}g(z)=1$, then defining the sigma algebra as the set of all subsets of $\mathcal{Z}$ and defining $P:2^{\mathcal{Z}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by 
$$ P[A] = \sum_{z \in A} g(z) \quad \forall A \subseteq \mathcal{Z}$$
yields a valid probability measure, meaning that all three axioms of probability hold.